# Cambiar columna BD SQL por otra (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

En mi base de datos tengo una tabla con una serie de fármacos identificados con un número, (como si fuese un diccionario), y me ha llegado otra tabla en la que se incluyen los fármacos por su nombre. Necesito cambiar los nombres de esta segunda columna por sus identificadores correspondientes, pero no logro hacerlo.

Esta es la tabla de los fármacos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta, la tabla en la que se incluyen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito cambiar en la segunda tabla los nombres por sus id,

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido! Es recomendable poner el código que has intentado para ver cuál es el problema que te surge. Te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Así harás mejores preguntas y podrás ser ayudado en tus problemas!!

Comment: Como bien dice @RubialesAlberto, es necesario que muestres lo que has intentado y qué problemas o errores tienes en base a eso. Por otra parte, viendo la segunda tabla, **lo que realmente convendría sería normalizarla**, creando una nueva tabla con las columnas (id_drugs, id_tumor, id_farmaco, dosis)  y metiendo **filas individuales por cada fármaco usando el ID de la 1ª tabla**. No sé de qué trate tu aplicación, pero el modelo de la segunda tabla no sobrevivirá a la mínima evolución que ocurra en ella y ciertas consultas como contar el uso de un determinado fármaco serán harto complicadas.

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por los consejos, intentaré en próximas ocasiones preguntar de manera más clara y siguiendo un orden. En cuanto a esta pregunta, agradezco la respuesta de @A.Cedano , he pensado en la escalabilidad de la base en la app y tiene razón, es mejor y más sencillo utilizar una fila para cada fármaco, y de esa manera, además, me ha sido posible resolver el primer problema. La segunda tabla me llegó así del cliente, pero me parece una mejor idea modificarla para que en un futuro sea más útil. Muchas gracia a los dos!